# Manual order of columns in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'strength':['00-05','00-05','05-10','10-15'], 
                        'direction':['N','NWN','N','NEN'],
                        'count': [1, 1, 1, 1]})
order = ['NWN', 'N', 'NEN']
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(
        test_df,
        index=['strength'],
        columns=['direction'],
        aggfunc=len,
        fill_value=0
    )
pivot_table = pivot_table[order]
print(pivot_table)
```

But I get the error

```
KeyError: "['NWN' 'N' 'NEN'] not in index"
```

If I delete the column 'count', there is no error.
How can I order the columns?

Comment: Try to add `values='count'` to [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) so you avoid ending up with a [*MultiIndex*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html).